# HTML Table not Appearing in RStudio Viewer but Only as Code in the Console - Why?

Tags: r

I'm new to making tables in R and using html. I have R on two different laptops, and when working on one of the computers, when I use htmlTable, xtable, etc, a table appears in the viewer on the ride side of RStudio. However, on the other computer, no table displays in the viewer but html code appears in the console. Is there another package I need to render the html? I'm not using Markdown or anything, I just want to see simple tables using htmlTable in the viewer instead of the code.

I'm not sure how to make this reproducible, so I'm hoping someone knows the answer. On the computer that shows the actual table in the viewer, all I do is load the htmlTable package, and it works.

What am I missing? Is it related to my computer's settings, version of RStudio, etc?

Comment: It depends on the package. `xtable` just returns HTML code, which you can then insert into your document. Among others, `knitr::kable` and most LaTeX formatters do the same. Some packages generate a complete HTML widget that will display in the viewer, e.g. DT.

Comment: In this case, some package on one of the OP's dystopian systems has defined a `print.html` S3 method and it is taking the lead for `print`ing since the class for `htmlTable` objects is `c("html", "htmlTable", "character")`. OP shld debug that OR do `class(object_returned_from_call_to_htmlTable) <-  c("htmlTable", "html", "character")` before just calling `print()` OR explicitly call `htmltools::html_print(object_returned_from_call_to_htmlTable)` to achieve consistency in RStudio Viewer pane usage across their systems.

Comment: Using htmltools::html_print worked! Thanks. If you make it an official answer I can give credit.

Answer (score 3):

It was a bug. While I used

```
if(!code) htmltools::html_print(out_html) else out_html
```

as [@hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839543/html-table-not-appearing-in-rstudio-viewer-but-only-as-code-in-the-console-why/48132724#comment74715822_43839543) suggested in the comments, it seems the fix was among [Changes for 1.10](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/htmlTable/NEWS) so it is now (v. 1.11.1) possible to just

```
output <- matrix(1:4,ncol=2,
    dimnames = list(list("Row 1", "Row 2"),
                    list("Column 1", "Column 2")))
print(htmlTable::htmlTable(output,useViewer=TRUE))
```

and I can simply use `useViewer=!code` in my wrapper functions. Note you can also do

```
print(htmlTable::htmlTable(output,useViewer=utils::browseURL))
```

as the documentation suggests.