# htmlTable() output not going to the RStudio viewer: instead showing output as HTML code in console

Tags: html, r, rstudio

This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839543/html-table-not-appearing-in-rstudio-viewer-but-only-as-code-in-the-console-why) but with no satisfactory answer. Maybe the tagging of previous question was incorrect. If you know RSTUDIO settings as well as HTML then you may be the best person to answer.

Consider this example:

```
library(htmlTable)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=21:30)
htmlTable:: htmlTable(df)
```

The output is HTML code instead of the table.

```
 <table class='gmisc_table' style='border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;' >
<thead>
<tr>
<th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-top: 2px solid grey;'> </th>
<th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>x</th>
<th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>y</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>1</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>1</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>2</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>2</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>3</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>3</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>4</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>4</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>5</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>5</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>6</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>6</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>7</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>7</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>27</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>8</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>8</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: left;'>9</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>9</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>29</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: left;'>10</td>
<td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>10</td>
<td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>30</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Seems some settings of rstudio got disturbed as the output is supposed to be a HTML formatted table inside the RStudio viewer.

I tried

```
htmlTable:: htmlTable(df) %>% htmltools::html_print()
```

> Error in viewer(index_html) : could not find function "viewer"

It seems the viewer is not set for Rstudio - must be a simple setting somewhere.

Comment: I will suggest upgrade Rstudio.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I upgraded RStudio so at least now the html_print goes to the rstudio viewer pane. But I still have to use html_print. Earlier even the htmlTable output was going straight to viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The print happens in the `print.htmlTable`, since it is a basic S3 class all it requires is:

1. the function to be available (should be after loading the package)
2. the htmlTable to be of class `htmlTable`, i.e. when you call `class(htmlTable(df))` you should get [1] "htmlTable" "character"